# Allure Cucumber JVM adaptor - reporting showing Without feature Without Story

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber-jvm, allure

I'm using Allure reports with CucumberJVM for Selenium browser testing purpose.Followed below link for configuration
https://github.com/clicman/allure-cucumber-jvm-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Most of the Features and Scenarios are shown properly in the report except few of them which are shown as Without feature and Without Story
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You using outdated fork of examples. Try this original one: https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-cucumber-jvm-example

Comment: I'm using `<allure.version>1.6.0</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure.jvm.adaptopr.version>1.6.1</allure.jvm.adaptopr.version>                     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>` still getting the same issue for some scenarios [Without feature Without Story]

Comment: Take a look at example project, try to run it and give feedback. If it runs fine, provide more details of your project.